# Why is my comparator called twice when inserting it a set?

Tags: c++, stl, set, comparator

I was trying to see how a comparator works in cpp. So when I am inserting `s1`, the comparator operator is not called, which makes sense. But when `s2` is being inserted the comparator operator was called twice. Why?
When I checked, I found that both times when it was being called first arg to comparator was `s2`, while second arg was `s1`. Can anyone explain me this.

```
#include <set>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using std::string;

// Student Class
class student {
public:
    // To store Name and Roll Number
    string name;
    int rollnum;

    // Overloaded Constructor
    student(string name, int rollnum)
    {
        this->name = name;
        this->rollnum = rollnum;
    }
};

// Comparator Class to compare 2 objects
class studentcompare {
public:
    // Comparator function
    bool operator()(const student& a,
                    const student& b) const
    {
        std::cout << a.name << "::" << b.name << std::endl;
        return a.name < b.name;
    }
};

// Driver Code
int main()
{
    // Object of class student
    student s1("Raj", 23);
    student s2("Prerna", 24);

    std::set<student, studentcompare> s;
    s.insert(s1);
    s.insert(s2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Highly irrelevant to the issue, but a note: Your constructor is doubly-inefficient. It assigns rather than initializing the member variables (so they get default-initialized, then reassigned in the body) and it copy-assigns the `name` even though it received by value and could move-assign. Better version is: `student(string name, int rollnum) : name{std::move(name)}, rollnum{rollnum} {}`

Comment: Assume the very simplest algorithm always inserting new elements as a leaf dropping the element downwards – if you insert *sorted* data you get an entirely degenerate tree structurally equal to doubly linked list – to avoid, there exist algorithms to assure a minimum balance level like AVL trees or red-black trees, the latter being implemented in `std::set` (and `std::map` as well). These trees re-order their elements by some kind of rotations of nodes within subtrees – and I'd assume this additional comparison arises within this process (though no proof for, thus no answer...).

Comment: I'm not sure why it can compare only once, it need at least 2 compare to check it's not equal. ... oh wait the number is not the order.

Comment: @appleapple You don't need to check for equality if you already know that the element is less – only if that first check fails you need to do the inverse check to decide if greater or equal...

Comment: *But when s2 is being inserted the comparator operator was called twice. Why?* -- Maybe your runtime is doing a check to see whether the comparator follows a *strict-weak-order*.  That's how the Visual C++ debug runtime detects these errors.  Are you using Visual C++?  If so, are you running a debug build?

Comment: Could you paste the exact output ?

Answer (score 0):

That seem to be implementation dependent.

If you run your code on gcc, you get the double call, and if you run it with clang, you do not:

https://godbolt.org/z/z7xMKaqqf

(and MSVC does two calls, but with the arguments switched)

Comment: That's rather a comment than an answer...

Answer (score 0):

The `std::set` container is an associative container that stores unique keys, which are sorted with respect to a strict weak ordering criterion. It is implemented as a self-balancing binary search tree (BST).

This means that an insert operation requires to perform two sub-operations:

- find the position where the new key is to be inserted;
- check whether the key already exists.

The last sub-operation is necessary to guarantee that duplicate keys are not inserted. Indeed, the comparator requires to be called twice in order to determine whether two keys are equivalent.

```cpp
equiv(a, b) == !comp(a, b) && !comp(b, a)
```

In your example, the first insert operation does not perform any find or check, since `s1` is inserted in an empty collection. However, the second insert operation requires to call the comparator in order to get if `s2` should be added as the left-child or right-child of the root and then call another time the comparator in order to check whether `s2` is equivalent to `s1`.